# ionic overwrite active element css style

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'd like to change the css style of an activated element.

[Here's](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/mpkDd) a ionic-list you can see.

I tried to set the css style of the aktivated element like this:

```
.item-content.activated{
    background-color: rgba(0,100,255, 0.5);
}
```

That doesn't change anything

In the css-framework of ionic I have this line that sets the style of the activated elements:

```
.item.active, .item.activated, .item-complex.active .item-content, .item-complex.activated .item-content, .item .item-content.active, .item .item-content.activated      
{
   border-color: #ccc;
   background-color: #D9D9D9; 
}
```

If I change it in the framework, it works. But I only want it to be applied on list items and in my own css-stylesheet ... How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the selector:

`.item .item-content.activated`

It has the additional `.item` so more [**specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) which is why it is overriding the one you have written.

Comment: Oh, and I have to add !important ... then is it working

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as follows

```
.item.active,
.item.activated,
.item-complex.active .item-content,
.item-complex.activated .item-content,
.item .item-content.active,
.item .item-content.activated {
    color: #493F0B;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-color: #eee;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
```